# Compiler Not Resolving Default Typed Function Parameter

Tags: scala, function, types, functional-programming

I have a function that takes a typed sort function as a parameter, and I want this sort function to have a default parameter:

```
def foo[T](sort: MyObject => T = _.position)(implicit o: Ordering[T])
```

`MyObject.position` returns an `Int`.

Understandably, I am getting this error:

```
Expression of type (MyObject) => Int doesn't conform to expected type (MyObject) => T
```

OK, but I was hoping that the compiler would figure out that in the default case `T` is `Int` and check that an `Ordering[Int]` is available in `implicit` scope.

How can I help the compiler resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an overloaded function with and without an argument:

```
def foo(): FooResult = foo(_.position)
def foo[T](sort: MyObject => T)(implicit o: Ordering[T]): FooResult = ???
```

---

I can think up one way though, how to actually do it with a non-overloaded function (and some boilerplate).

You can take a special argument, which packs the `sort` function, the ordering and even the implementation of `foo`, and provide an implicit conversion from a suitable function to this argument. This is basically an application of the [Magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/).

```
sealed trait Magnet {
  type T

  val sort: MyObject => T
  implicit val o: Ordering[T] 

  def fooImpl = ???
}

object Magnet {
  implicit def fromSort[T0](sortArg: MyObject => T0)(implicit ordArg: Ordering[T0]): Magnet = 
    new Magnet {
      type T = T0

      val sort = sortArg
      val o = ordArg
    }
}

def foo(sort: Magnet = (_: MyObject).position) = sort.fooImpl
```

One drawback is that this loses the expected type for the argument, so you have to specify the type of the argument of the `sort` function.

The usability for your case is questionable, but it's still an interesting solution nevertheless and may be useful in other situations.

Comment: I was hoping to use the type system in some clever way to avoid the boilerplate of an overloaded method, but this works.

Comment: @Vidya I've added a way to do it with a non-overloaded function, though I think in your case the first solution is simpler and better.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.